# How can I produce one whole string from iteration on array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, formatting, string-formatting

I have array of arrays looking something like this :

```
arr = [[f,f,f,f,f], [f,f,t,f,f], [f,t,f,t,f]]
```

and am I outputing it formatted on the console like this:

```
arr.each {|a| puts a.join.gsub('t','<b></b>').gsub('f','<i></i>')}
```

and it generates something like this:

```
<i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
<i></i><i></i><b></b><i></i><i></i>
<i></i><b></b><i></i><b></b><i></i>
```

but it is only in the output. I am wondering how I can assign it to a string? With the new lines and everything, exactly the way it looks,

Comment: where did you get it i and b tag from ???.

Comment: I have forgotten to code it

Comment: I have made some stupid assumptions on your behalf and you can check my answer below, assuming that f and t are strings and you want to replace them with i tag and b tag respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a= [["f","f","f","f","f"], ["f","f","t","f","f"], ["f","t","f","t","f"]].map do |arr|
  arr.join.gsub(/[ft]/) do |x|
    if x =~ /f/
      '<i></i>'
    elsif x =~ /t/
      '<b></b>'
    end
  end
end.join("\n")
puts a 
# >> <i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
# >> <i></i><i></i><b></b><i></i><i></i>
# >> <i></i><b></b><i></i><b></b><i></i>
```

Comment: +1... I think it is enough..

Comment: When I copy/paste it in the IRB it outputs it on the same line

Comment: @user2128702 did you copy the puts portion of the code too and hit enter after copying???

Comment: @bjhaid :D This is funny but I just had to touch it a little bit cause in my case the values are not exactly the same and I had to change the Regex , but thaks anyways!